# post type to show posts instead of pages

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

i am working on a wordpress site using the theme called **[Spacious](http://demo.themegrill.com/spacious/)**.the theme supports a widget to show some pages as recent works .the widget name is **TG:Featured Widget**  . here is the code that i got from the theme core files.

```
/**
 * Featured recent work widget to show pages.
 */
class spacious_recent_work_widget extends WP_Widget {
function spacious_recent_work_widget() {
    $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'widget_recent_work', 'description' => __( 'Show your some pages as recent work. Best for Business Top or Bottom sidebar.', 'spacious' ) );
    $control_ops = array( 'width' => 200, 'height' =>250 ); 
    parent::WP_Widget( false, $name = __( 'TG: Featured Widget', 'spacious' ), $widget_ops, $control_ops);
}

function form( $instance ) {
    for ( $i=0; $i<3; $i++ ) {
        $var = 'page_id'.$i;
        $defaults[$var] = '';
    }
    $att_defaults = $defaults;
    $att_defaults['title'] = '';
    $att_defaults['text'] = '';
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $att_defaults );
    for ( $i=0; $i<3; $i++ ) {
        $var = 'page_id'.$i;
        $var = absint( $instance[ $var ] );
    }
    $title = esc_attr( $instance[ 'title' ] );
    $text = esc_textarea($instance['text']);
    ?>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', 'spacious' ); ?></label> 
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
    </p>
    <?php _e( 'Description','spacious' ); ?>
    <textarea class="widefat" rows="10" cols="20" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('text'); ?>"><?php echo $text; ?></textarea>
    <?php
    for( $i=0; $i<3; $i++) { 
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( key($defaults) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Page', 'spacious' ); ?>:</label>
            <?php wp_dropdown_pages( array( 'show_option_none' =>' ','name' => $this->get_field_name( key($defaults) ), 'selected' => $instance[key($defaults)] ) ); ?>
        </p>
    <?php
    next( $defaults );// forwards the key of $defaults array
    }
}

function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance[ 'title' ] = strip_tags( $new_instance[ 'title' ] );
    for( $i=0; $i<3; $i++ ) {
        $var = 'page_id'.$i;
        $instance[ $var] = absint( $new_instance[ $var ] );
    }
    if ( current_user_can('unfiltered_html') )
        $instance['text'] =  $new_instance['text'];
    else
        $instance['text'] = stripslashes( wp_filter_post_kses( addslashes($new_instance['text']) ) ); // wp_filter_post_kses() expects slashed
    $instance['filter'] = isset($new_instance['filter']);

    return $instance;
}

function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    extract( $args );
    extract( $instance );

    global $post;
    $title = isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ? $instance[ 'title' ] : '';
    $text = apply_filters( 'widget_text', empty( $instance['text'] ) ? '' : $instance['text'], $instance );
    $page_array = array();
    for( $i=0; $i<3; $i++ ) {
        $var = 'page_id'.$i;
        $page_id = isset( $instance[ $var ] ) ? $instance[ $var ] : '';

        if( !empty( $page_id ) )
            array_push( $page_array, $page_id );// Push the page id in the array
    }
    $get_featured_pages = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page'            => -1,
        'post_type'                 =>  array( 'page' ),
        'post__in'                  => $page_array,
        'orderby'                   => 'post__in'
    ) );
    echo $before_widget;
    ?>
        <div class="tg-one-fourth tg-column-1">
            <?php
            if ( !empty( $title ) ) { echo $before_title . esc_html( $title ) . $after_title; } ?>
            <p><?php echo esc_textarea( $text ); ?></p>
        </div>
            <?php
            $i=2;
            while( $get_featured_pages->have_posts() ):$get_featured_pages->the_post();
                if ( $i % 4 == 0 ) { $class = 'tg-one-fourth tg-one-fourth-last'.' tg-column-'.$i; }
                elseif( $i % 3 == 0 ) { $class= 'tg-one-fourth tg-after-two-blocks-clearfix'.' tg-column-'.$i; }
                else { $class = 'tg-one-fourth'.' tg-column-'.$i; }
                $page_title = get_the_title();
                ?>  
                <div class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
                    <?php 
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail( ) ) {
                        echo '<div class="service-image"><a title="'.get_the_title().'" href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID,'featured-blog-medium').'</a></div>';                
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>          
            <?php 
                $i++;
            endwhile;
            // Reset Post Data
            wp_reset_query(); 
            ?>
    <?php echo $after_widget;
    }
}
```

the above code part has the below spinet which asks for post type .its has given **page** .I changed that to **'post'**

```
$get_featured_pages = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page'            => -1,
        'post_type'                 =>  array( 'page' ),
        'post__in'                  => $page_array,
        'orderby'                   => 'post__in'
    ) );
```

still it is not working, can anyone please help?

Comment: What's not working exactly?  If the admin screen isn't showing posts, you may need to add a `post_type` argument to the [`wp_dropdown_pages`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages#Other_Parameters) function.  If the admin screen is showing posts, but they're not appearing in the front end, you may need to change the `post_type` argument in the `WP_Query` constructor.

Comment: it is not showing in admin page .what can be done? please help

Comment: _What's_ not showing in the admin page?  The widget isn't showing at all?  Posts are not showing in the dropdown?

Comment: posts are not showing ,,the pages are showing

Comment: Did you add the `post_type` argument to the `wp_dropdown_pages` call as I suggested (`'post_type' => 'post'`)?

Comment: i added the following <?php wp_dropdown_pages( array( 'show_option_none' =>' ','name' => $this->get_field_name( key($defaults) ),'post_type' => 'post', 'selected' => $instance[key($defaults)] ) ); ?> but now the dropdown itself is not showing

Comment: Ah, sorry; looking at [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152561/wp-dropdown-pages-returns-empty-string-for-post-type-anything-other-then-page) it won't work because the `post` post type is not hierarchical. You may have to write your own function to replace that call.

Comment: A quick Google returned [this page](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-create-a-drop-down-list-for-posts-on-wordpress/).  Not sure if the code is any good - I haven't had a look (gotta get back to work).